# Google sign in custom button

Tags: google-signin

I migrated from https://apis.google.com/js/client:platform.js to https://accounts.google.com/gsi/client. I need to use a my custom google login button in order to have similar UX with other buttons.

How can I do it?

Google button works but it is rendered using google style.

```
window.onload = function () {
      google.accounts.id.initialize({
        client_id: "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
        callback: handleCredentialResponse
      });
      google.accounts.id.renderButton(
        document.getElementById("glogin"),
        { type: "icon", size: "medium" }  // customization attributes
      );
      //google.accounts.id.prompt(); // also display the One Tap dialog
    }
```

My custom html button is:

```
<li id="glogin"><a href="#"><img src="assets/images/land_login/auth_google.png" alt=""></a></li>
```

Please help me. I can't found solution on google official documentation.

Comment: Hi, Have you found any way to do the change?

Answer (score 0):

I faced same issue and it seems we cannot use custom button with gsi.

However, you can modify iframe render button by using given options.
It was not enough to me btw.

If you go with html api, you can [generate Html code](https://developers.google.com/identity/gsi/web/tools/configurator).
If you go with javascript api, you can check the options [here](https://developers.google.com/identity/gsi/web/reference/js-reference#GsiButtonConfiguration).

I am trying this [node package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/google-oauth-gsi) now. I will let you know if it works.

Comment: Did the node package work well?

Comment: @RossRawlins yes it did work. but there was a minor issue to me. Therefore, I just followed following link.
https://developers.google.com/identity/gsi/web/guides/overview